# Android Gson ignoring object type adapter in list<object>

Tags: android, gson, deserialization

```
class Response<T>(
        JHeader header;
        T result;
)

class JHeader(
        Int success;
        List<String> error;
)

class Character{
    @SerializedName("id_") Int id;
    @SerializedName("levelA") String level
    @SerializedName("a3") unit: String = "

    Character(Int id, String level) {
        this.id = id
        this.level= level
    }
}

Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build()

public Observable<Response<List<Character>>> getCharacterById(characterID: Int){
        return apiService.getCharacter(characterID)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
```

And i have a custom type adapter made for Character.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Character.class, new CharacterTypeAdapter());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Gson is completly ignoring my type adapter while deserializing the list so i guess because of generic type erasure, the List gets treated like a List Object or something, so my adapter wont be used.

Using Retrofit2. Is there any way i can do his with generics, without having to create custom classes for Lists every time i need to parse a response which contains a list?